# How do I display a number of buttons combined in taskbard under 1 group in Windows7- the same way as it was displayed in WindowsXP by default?

Tags: windows-7, taskbar

I want Win7 taskbar to display number of buttons combined under 1 group by the way it is done in WinXP by default - there is a number of buttons and then the name of group, while in Win7 there is only the name of group...

Answer (score 0):

If I get this correctly you want the number of grouped tabs to be displayed.

There is no way you can do that through win 7 taskbar settings..

[This article from Lifehacker](http://lifehacker.com/5532578/the-power-users-guide-to-the-windows-7-taskbar) shows settings, shortcuts and a probable solution for you: reverting back to XP style taskbar.

[In here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/281628) Microsoft helps you customize how taskbar groups tabs, which might be alternative for you.